# Фильтрация в Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Извините, может вопрос глупый, но я уже весь мозг сломал.

Задача: Отфильтровать товары по цвету.

Есть индекс

```
{
    "settings" : {
        "analysis" : {
          "analyzer" : {
            "default": {
              "type": "custom",
              "filter": [
                "standard",
                "lowercase",
                "english_stemmer",
                "english_stop_words"
              ],
              "tokenizer": "lowercase"
            }
          },
          "filter" : {
            "english_stemmer" : {
              "type" : "stemmer",
              "language" : "english"
            },
            "english_stop_words" : {
              "type" : "stop",
              "stopwords" : "_english_"
            }
          }
        }   },   "mappings" : {
        "products": {
          "properties" : {
            "id" : { "type" : "integer"},
            "name" : { "type" : "string" },
            "description" : { "type" : "string" },
            "price" : { "type" : "integer"},
            "meta_title" : { "type" : "string" },
            "meta_keywords" : { "type" : "string" },
            "meta_description" : { "type" : "string" },
            "rating" : { "type" : "integer"},
            "category_id" : {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
            },
            "category_name" : { "type": "string" },
            "color" : { "type": "string" },
            "brand_id" : { "type": "integer" },
            "brand_name" : { "type": "string" }
          }
        }   
    } 
}
```

Цвет - строка.

я уже перепробовал кучу вариантов и ни один не фильтрует результаты.

```
{
     "query": {
         "filtered": {
             "query": {
                 "match_all": {}
             },
             "filter": {
                 "bool": {
                     "should": [{
                         "term": {
                             "color": "White"
                         }
                     }]
                 }
             }
         }
     }
}
```

или

```
{   "bool": {
    "filter" : [
        {
            "terms" : {
                "color" : "white"
            }
        }
    ]   }  }
```

или

```
{
    "query" : {
        "term" : { "color" : "White" }
    }
}
```

И еще наверное с тысячу различных вариантов из интернета, и всё равно ES просто выдаёт результаты как ему заблагорассудится, среди которых может вообще не быть цвета White даже вхождения этой строки.

Кто-нибудь может объяснить как вообще можно фильтровать по строковому полю в ElasticSearch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас проблема в маппинге. По дефолту все строки проходят через работу анализаторов. Нужно обновить маппинг, чтобы было

```
{
  "color": {
    "type": "string",
    "index": "not_analyzed"
  }
}
```

После того, как изменился маппинг, данные в индексе нужно обновить. И только после этого у вас будет работать фильтрация по term-у.

Более подробно об этом можно прочитать [тут](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/mapping-intro.html).

Comment: а можно использовать поле color.RAW ?