# ElasticSearch. Как выбрать все записи по массиву?

Tags: запрос, elasticsearch

Имеется следующий маппинг у индекса:

```
{
  "message": {
    "type": "text"
  },
  "type": {
    "type": "long"
  },
  "token": {
    "type": "text",
    "fielddata": true
  },
  "params": {
    "properties": {
      "api": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Необходимо выбрать мессаджи, у которых токены в ходят в перечень и АПИ по условию или тип равен 1.

Код такой:

```
'query' => array(
    'bool' => array(
        'filter' => array(
            'terms' => array('token' => array("5853b5d17cbaeb0245a85cfa5afe5bf1", "5853b56abf708aa0cf0f0e562a9fe513")),
        ),
        'should' => array(
            array('match' => array('params.api' => "api_shop")),
            array('match' => array('type' => 1)),
        ),
        "minimum_should_match" => 1,
    )
),
</code>

Результат не радует
<code>
array (
  'total' => 0,
  'max_score' => 0,
  'hits' => 
  array ()
```

Перебором стало понятно что не отрабатывает `filter`.

Есть подозрение на тип поля токен в маппинге.

Answer (score 1):

Тут подглядел ([Фильтрация в Elasticsearch](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/532275/%D0%A4%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-elasticsearch?rq=1)) и помогло.
Отключил анализирование params.api, корректно заработало.